# BCS is to get external data into SP, what about the other way around?

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, reporting-services, data

I am going to migrate/update our SP 2010 to 2013 or 2016 (depending on when it actually gets released). Preferably cloud.

What our fear is currently is... if we go cloud will we *really* have access to our data?  Can we report our SP data using SSRS out of it?  I hear with SP lists you can get data via OData, but you can't use OData in SSRS!

So... I found BCS - and that seems to let you use external data within sharepoint. but does it allow a way to get SP data down to a local server?

Comment: Two question, are you going to Office365 or are you going to host you're own farm in the cloud? If you're going to O365, do you really need SSRS? Or are you just looking for any means to report on SharePoint data? If the last, have a look at PowerBI. That should work great with SharePoint and is also a cloud solution.

Comment: O365.  Do I really need SSRS?  Well let me explain like this...  My boss wants to "make sure we have full data access to SharePoint Online" meaning, our reports will be (must be) generated through SSRS pulling from a SQL Server instance. I have seen a little bit of power BI but honestly I would have to sell him on it and I'm not prepare to do that. Too much time involved and I couldn't prove the point, unfortunately. Unless you could help me do that?

Comment: I'm still not pretty clear on the SSRS part, but you do have full data access to SharePoint online, as you have with onpremise (unless you're going directly to the db, which isn't supported anyway). For online there are only two methods of accessing data. Either C# code and CSOM or the REST endpoint. And I'm assuming neither of these work directly with SSRS.
You could always sync the data to a local SQL table and report on that, but that sounds like a lot of work.

Comment: we have some reports that just read out of the db directly from onprem in our 2010 environment - nothing more than read/select statements. i think youre right that the SCOM and REST stuff does not work with SSRS. we might end up trying to sync to a local sql database, if we aren't able to report directly out of sharepoint with powerBI.  one question on powerBI - can I publish those powerBI files onto a sql report server along side .rdl files?  can I also put them onto asp.net sites?

Comment: I'm not very experienced on PowerBI, but I'm pretty sure you can't publish them on a SSRS server. I do think you could embed them on pages. The easiest method being an iframe.

Comment: the problem with an iframe is every iframe seems to prompt the user for credentials independently - like if accessing an intranet site mapped to an external facing url/port.  so im trying to avoid that situation. 

As far ass PowerBI/SSRS on prem servers... it looks like it is coming: http://blogs.technet.com/b/dataplatforminsider/archive/2015/10/29/microsoft-business-intelligence-our-reporting-roadmap.aspx